# Read json file using localhost

Tags: json

After spending a few days researching this issue, I still didn't get how to read my json file using localhost. Situation is the next: I need to create a tabs. I'm using react and redux. All info about tabs is in json file. I need to read that and for each item there I'll apply some code (not important). To add more tabs, you need only add more items inside that json file. So, I can't upload this file to any service and use the link from there, because there will be a problem (when you add some tabs in json file , you have to upload it again). I know that browsers don't allow to work with local files. So the question is how can I work with json file using localhost? I understand that there are many such questions in Internet, but there are no normal answer, that I can use.

Comment: If you are comfortable loading js file. You can create some function in js file that will return your json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your JSON file under src folder. And then import the file using webpack. Like below

```
import data from './data.json';
```